# Can't locate IO/Pty.pm - but it is installed

Tags: rhel, perl, module

I have a script that I inherited from another developer and am trying to make it work on a new RHEL server.  The script uses Expect.pm which 'uses' IO/Pty (and IO/Tty).

The issue is, when I run this script, it claims it cannot locate IO/Pty.pm.  The path to both IO modules is /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO. This path is in my @INC.

I have verified the permissions match what other functioning modules have (also tried 775 as a test).

The only difference on the new server vs old is the version of Expect.pm and IO/Pty and IO/Tty (newer versions on the new server).

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Here is the error:

```
[Tue Dec 17 14:33:51.284748 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 64712] [client redacted:63776] AH01215: Can't locate IO/Pty.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /usr/local/share/perl5/Expect.pm line 23


drwxr-xr-x. 17 root root 4096 May  8  2019 /usr
drwxr-xr-x. 18 root root 4096 May 20  2019 /usr/local
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Jul 12 13:44 /usr/local/lib64
drwxr-x---   4 root root 4096 Dec 17 12:18 /usr/local/lib64/perl5
drwxr-x---   4 root root 4096 Dec 17 12:18 /usr/local/lib64/perl5/
drwxrwxr-x   3 root root 4096 Dec 17 14:56 /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO
-rwxrwxr-x   1 root root 9114 Sep 12  2014 /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO/Pty.pm
-rwxrwxr-x   1 root root 8096 Sep 12  2014 /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO/Tty.pm
```

Comment: `ls -ld /usr /usr/local /usr/local/lib64 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO /usr/local/lib64/perl5/IO/???.pm` [please](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/557745/edit).

Comment: Updated w/ output (currently on higher permissions than normal since I was trying to figure out if that was the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application almost certainly doesn't have access to one of the intermediate directories:

> ```
> drwxr-x---   4 root root 4096 Dec 17 12:18 /usr/local/lib64/perl5
> ```

You can fix this (as root) with `chmod o+rx /usr/local/lib64/perl5`

Comment: Doing that helped, I ended up doing a chmod -R to just catch everything in each of the @INC folders and after installing some more modules that (and fixing their permissions) I managed to get the script to work.